# Windows 7 Media Player duplicate mp3 files in library

Tags: windows-media-player

I keep my .mp3 files in C:\Users\myname\Music\mp3 to manage my library.

Have a look at the image below,

[image]

But windows media player always lists duplicate mp3 files in album playlist. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I encountered this problem sometime back and after googling I found the solution.Don't have the link with me but I remember the solution. Here's it

Click Start > type ***services***

Find ***WMPNetworkSvc*** in the list then right-click and select ***Stop*** Service

Go to %localappdata%\Microsoft\Media Player

Find the ***CurrentDatabase_371.wmdb*** file and delete it.

Start Windows Media Player once again. Hopefully should be fixed.

Comment: I did what you said, and updated my library, but problems persistes.

Comment: its seems its now working. Started 10 times wmp and played few songs, no problems for now.

Comment: no problems for now i'll marked this as answered